# gmake wildcard function not generating target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm using gmake on Windows with MinGW. This is a snippet of the makefile:

```
SRCS = ..\path\to\srcs\*.c*
SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRCS))
OBJS := $(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(SRCS)))

$(OBJS) : $(SRCS)
    $(CC) $(FLGAS) $(INCLUDES) "$<"
```

I'm getting the following:

> gmake: *** No targets.  Stop.

If I define `SRCS`, for instance, as `..\path\to\srcs\a.c`, it works.
Am I using `wildcard` in the correct manner?

I'm using `GNU Make 3.81`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make` doesn't cope well with backslashes; you need to double each, or (better) switch to forward slashes instead.

Your recipe overrides the built-in rules for creating object files from C files with a broken one, though.
Your recipe claims that all `$(OBJS)` will be produced from a single compilation which has all the `$(SRCS)` as dependencies, but only reads the first one (`$<` pro `$^`). It's probably better to just say what you want and let `make` take it from there.

```
.PHONY: all
all: $(OBJS)
%.o: ../path/to/srcs/%.c
```